# Locked out of S-Color K60 Android

Tags: locked-out

I recently purchased an Android phone that i sent to my mom. But my little brother put some gesture password and forgot it! My mother dont know the gesture, kid is unable to recall and starts weeping whenever asked about it. As far as i remember USB Debugging was never enabled. Below are the options i have given a try to.

1. Now when connected to my laptop, i am unable to detect the phone as it is in locked state (Detected but not accessible).
2. Tried the wipe data/factory reset option through Android system recovery <3e> menu and once rebooted, it again asks for the gesture key.
3. In Recovery mode, it shows apply update from ADB but unable to find TWRP recovery zip file for my device (S-Color K60)!
4. In Recovery mode, it shows apply update from sdcard, i tried sideloading Pattern-Password-disable.zip from xda, but it said Installing System Updates, then it said Error and later showed Installation aborted.
5. Tried calling from other number and click back button multiple times to get back to the same lock screen!
6. Tried going to Emergency call dial pad and click numbers randomly with no luck.
7. When connected to my laptop and run adb devices command, it shows List of devices attached but the list is Blank, however when i got to apply update from ADB on phone and try to list the devices connected, it gives a sideload menu on phone with a serial number followed by sideload on my cmd screen.

So after too much internet search i could succeed in unlocking the phone yet. Are there any other ways to unlock my phone?
Device Details:
S-Color K60 (Something i got at a cheap price tag, link below for reference only)
https://www.wins4.com/s-color?product_id=15718&page=2

Comment: When you perform a factory reset if can not ask for the gesture key afterwards because that gesture is saved in used data that is erased when performing a factory reset. It can ask for the Google password (Factory Reset Protection). If your device is not a used device and it really asks for the gesture key after a successful factory reset it is defect. In such a case give the device back and get your money back.